# How to split two lists of the same class to different tables in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project I have the folowing classes:

```
public class Dot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    // some more information
}

public class TimeRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Dot> Fact { get; set; }
    public List<Dot> Forecast { get; set; }
}
```

And I want `Fact` and `Forecast` to be in different tables in database. Is there any good way to do so?

#### My thoughts

Probably I can make two classes `FactDot` and `ForecastDot`, that inherits class `Dot`, make properties `List<FactDot> Fact` and `List<ForecastDot> Forecast` and these lists will be in defferent tables, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: *but I don't think it's a good solution* -- Why isn't that a good solution? One class can't be mapped to two tables. But then, why two different tables?

Comment: @GertArnold It's sad that there is no way to have different tables(( 
In the future I want to add more Lists to `TimeRow` class, like: `OptimisticForecast`, `PessimisticForecast` and even one more `TimeRow_2` class. If they will store in one table, this table will have a lot of `Id's` columns, which is not good for understanding the structure of DB.

Comment: I think `TimeRow` should only have `Dots`,and `Dot` some sort of type field. In the business logic you can make the distinction, as in a `TimeRow` domain class that just returns various collections with a simple `Where`. That allows you to add as many types of dots as you want without ever changing the data model.

Comment: @GertArnold Hm... That will probably solve my problem, I'll try this out. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and these lists will be in defferent tables, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Actually, it is the good solution. :)

```
public class Dot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    // some more information
}

public class Fact : Dot
{ }

public class Forecast : Dot
{ }

public class TimeRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fact> Facts { get; set; } = new List<Fact>();
    public virtual ICollection<Forecast> Forecasts { get; set; } = new List<Forecast>();
}
```

Why?  Because it's only today that it doesn't feel necessary. A Fact and Forecast look like the identical thing so having 2 classes with the same fields feels "wrong".. But they aren't the same thing, even if they currently look identical. They need to be stored separately, and who's to say that down the road there won't be fields that would be really useful to only one of these entities? You won't want to add Null-able, conditional fields into Dot, it makes more sense to put a Fact-specific field into Fact. This keeps that avenue fully open.

If you add other classes that extend from Dot, so what? they're literally two lines of code and can rely on EF convention for mapping. :)  Inheriting Dot is simply a contract that they can be treated "as a" Dot. They still have their own distinct purpose even if the data they store does not differ *yet*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll probably continue working in this direction with different classes)

Answer (score 0):

Have a Forecast class with no fields that inherits from Dot.

```cs
public class Dot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    // some more information
}

public sealed class Forecast : Dot
{
}

public class TimeRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Dot> Fact { get; set; }
    public List<Forecast> Forecast { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In the future I want to add more Lists to `TimeRow class`, like: `OptimisticForecast`, `PessimisticForecast`. It means that I will have to add two more simple classes like `Forecast`. But in business logic I want to work with `Dots`, does it mean that I will nead one more class between DB and business logic to cast `TimeRow` to it?

Answer (score 0):

It is always the best idea to have only one table instead of two if it is possible. It allows to reuse alot of code and  make  the different queries much easier.
So I recommend:

```
public class Dot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int TimeRowId { get; set; } 
    public int DotType {get; set;} in this case you can use 0-Fact, 1-Forecast
    // or maybe this: public string DotType {get; set;} in this case you can use just "Fact" or "Forecast"

....  // some more information
}

public class TimeRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Dot> Dots { get; set; }
  
}
```

or maybe in your case you can find that it is better to move DotType from Dot to TimeRow class:

```
public class TimeRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 public int DotType {get; set;} in this case you can use 0-Fact, 1-Forecast
    // or maybe this: public string DotType {get; set;} in this case you can use just "Fact" or "Forecast"

    public virtual List<Dot> Dots { get; set; }
  
}
```